# Execute a command only one time discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to respond to a specific message only one time. For example if someone writes something the bots sais "someone did not say hello" if he writes something again the bot won't reply anymore. The command Im using keep saying error for the else

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
                if message.content.startswith('hi'):
                    print('hello')
                i=0                         
                else:
                    if i==0:
                        print('someone did not say hello')
                        i=i+1
```

Comment: Are you for example expecting `i` to be a global variable? How? Why?

Comment: how can I make the i variable global?

Answer (score 1):

Like someone said the variable i is not global, and will reset every time the function is run. Try setting the variable outside of the function, and then calling a global variable inside.

```
respond = True
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global respond #tells python to use and modify the respond variable declared outside the function
    if message.content.startswith('hi'):
        print('hello')                         
        else:
           if respond:
               print('someone did not say hello')
               respond = False
```